# How to get associated table's rows in eager loading: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**I have three Database Tables.**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblproject` (
  `ProjectID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectStatusID` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

CREATE TABLE `tblprojectSkills` (
  `ProjectSkillID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectID` int NOT NULL,
  `SkillID` int NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

CREATE TABLE `tblSkills` (
  `SkillID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Skill` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**In the above tables. `SkillID` is related in `tblSkills` and `tblprojectSkills`.
`ProjectID` is related in `Project` and `projectSkills` Table**

### **My project Model is below.**

```
class Project_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblproject";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ProjectSkills() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProjectSkill_Model', 'ProjectID');
    }        
}

class ProjectSkill_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojectskill";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectSkillID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}

class Skill_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblskill";
    protected $primaryKey = "SkillID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

### **Database Query in laravel 5.1 is below.**

```
\App\Models\Project\Project_Model
::with('ProjectSkills')
->where('ProjectID', '=', $ProjectID)->first();
```

### **Question**

I can get the Skill ID, But, How can I get the Skill Name from Skill Table ?

Comment: You have defined relations incorrectly - have a look at many-to-many relationship: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your validation is kicking in on every event, `focusout`, etc. Hence, I added following lines to have validation only after clicking the `button`:

```
onfocusout: false,
onkeyup: false,
onclick: false,
```

Secondly, inside your `CreateErrorMessage`, I have made minor changes so as to show all error messages at once. `Message` is an `object` and will have multiple error messages, hence it needs to go through `$.each`.

And lastly, 
you were checking for `ErrorMessages` inside the loop, which should ideally be outside, so that checking happens only once.

Below is the updated code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("form#loginForm").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    rules: {
      EmailAddress: "required",
      Password: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      EmailAddress: {
        required: "Please enter email"
      },
      Password: {
        required: "Please enter Password"
      }
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      RemoveErrorElements();
      CreateErrorMessage(errorList);
    }
  });
});

function CreateErrorMessage(errorList) {

  if ($(".panel-body").find("ul.ErrorMessages").length === 0) {
    $(".panel-body").prepend("<ul class='ErrorMessages'><ul>");
  }

  var ErrorMessages = $(".panel-body").find("ul.ErrorMessages");

  $.each(errorList, function(index, Message) {
    $(Message.element).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
    $(Message).each(function(k, v) {
      ErrorMessages.append("<li>" + v.message + "</li>");
    })

  });
}

function RemoveErrorElements() {
  $(".panel-body").find("ul.ErrorMessages").remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate="novalidate">
              <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="qZuutEkhKvETtiuA3stgpOyOiH7FrKXUPz7C7bxe">
              <div class="form-group has-error">
                <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-md-4 control-label">UserName / E-Mail Address</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input name="EmailAddress" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group has-error">
                <label for="Password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input name="Password" type="password" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Login
                                        </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Project_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblproject";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ProjectSkills() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProjectSkill_Model', 'ProjectID');
    }        
}

class ProjectSkill_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojectskill";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectSkillID";
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function Skills() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Skill_Model', 'ProjectSkillID');
    }
}

class Skill_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblskill";
    protected $primaryKey = "SkillID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**GET for skill name**

```
$project_info = \App\Models\Project\Project_Model->where('ProjectID', '=', $ProjectID)->first();

foreach($project_info->ProjectSkills as $ProjectSkills) {
     dd($ProjectSkills->skill_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what you pasted, you don't need an intermediate table. And add a foreign key `ProjectID` reference the `tblproject` table.

Change the relationship method in `Project_Model` like this:

```
public function Skills() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Skill_Model', 'ProjectID');
}
```

And execute the query statement:

```
$project = \App\Models\Project\Project_Model::where('ProjectID', $ProjectID)->with(['Skills' => function ($query) {
    $query->addSelect(['SkillID', 'Skill', 'ProjectID']);
}])->get();
```